# What could the syntax for a predicate, that should narrow down table results based on 4 textfields, look like?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, predicate

So I have 4 text fields in which a user can use to narrow down table results in order to find an exact place. My problem is that since a user does not have to type something in each text field, I can't simply use `AND` in my predicate.

Right now I have the opposite from what I'd like my app to do. If one types in a City and a State, my predicate shows more results rather than narrowing the results. Which makes perfect sense to why its doing that.

Other than creating many `if` statements based on what text fields are empty or not, is there an better way around this?

```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(place CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (city CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (state CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (zip CONTAINS[c] %@)",
                              userPlace, userCity, userState, userZip];
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are searching? Is it one string with userName, city, etc., or an array of dictionaries, or something else?

Comment: I'm using Core Data. My NSFetchedResultsController searches through my attributes. So I would look for the input 'userCity' in the 'city' attribute. I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ = \"\" OR place CONTAINS[c] %@) AND (%@ = \"\" OR city CONTAINS[c] %@) AND (%@ = \"\" OR state CONTAINS[c] %@) AND (%@ = \"\" OR zip CONTAINS[c] %@)",
                          userName, userName, userCity, userCity, userState, userState, userZip, userZip];
```

Comment: @rdelmar: you are right of course (thanks), edited. - I am not sure anymore that the test for empty fields is necessary at all, but I can test it only later when I have access to my computer again.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = nil;
NSMutableSting *predicateString = [NSMutableString string];
NSArray *attributeNames = @[@"name", @"city", @"state", @"zip"];
int i = 0; 
for (NSString *s in @[userName, userCity, userState, userZip]) {
   if (s && ![s isEqualToString:@""]) {
      [predicateString appendFormat:@"%@", 
          predicateString.length ? @" AND " : @""];
      [predicateString appendFormat:@"(%@ CONTAINS[c] '%@')", 
          attributeNames[i], s];
   }
   i++;
}
if (predicateString.length) { 
   fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
}
```

The "proper" way to do this is with compound predicates, but this would be even more verbose.

I also noticed a possible mismatch in your example between the attribute `place` and your substitution variable `userName`. Should it be `name`? `userPlace`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I just fixed that. Thanks for your help :)